# iOS Alamofire stop all requests

Tags: ios, alamofire

Is there any way I can for example say:

`Alamofire.Manager.cancelAllRequests()` or `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.cancelAllRequests()`?

Of course it would be great if these requests especially in case of image download would only be paused for later when I'll cal the same URL but... I need at least to be able to cancel all requests at a global level. Some suggestions ?

In my app I have a wrapper above the Alamofire.request(.Post....) way of doing things so I would really appreciate not making me create or interact with Manager class in another way besides that specified above.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use the `NSURLSession` methods directly to accomplish this.

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

This will call all your completion handlers with cancellation errors. If you need to be able to resume downloads, then you'll need to grab the `resumeData` from the request if it is available. Then use the resume data to resume the request in place when you're ready.

Comment: After calling this i am not able to make request again

Comment: Once you invalidate a session, you need to create a new one in order to make additional requests. It's all in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/invalidateAndCancel).

Comment: how can i create new ?

Comment: the new call is: `Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.invalidateAndCancel()`
its refactored with https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/ade5a2e18e81f58d9ea39a4223f79e396578dc78#diff-47e97757a068c92a8406e56b15e64465

Answer (score 68):

`cnoon`'s one-liner solution is great but it invalidates the NSURLSession and you need to create a new one.

Another solution would be this (iOS 7+):

```
session.getTasks { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
    dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
}
```

Or if you target iOS 9+ only:

```
session.getAllTasks { tasks in
    tasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
}
```

Comment: If you have not configured URLSession in alamofire, you can get default with `Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session`

Answer (score 16):

Below Code stops the Requests in [Swift 3]:

Plus the code works for **Alamofire v3 & v4** plus for **iOS 8+**.

```
func stopTheDamnRequests(){
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
            tasks.forEach{ $0.cancel() }
        }
    } else {
        Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (sessionDataTask, uploadData, downloadData) in
            sessionDataTask.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            uploadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            downloadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply Copy and paste the function.

Answer (score 2):

in completion to the @Loïs Di Qual you can check the request url and cancel (suspend, resume) the request that you need:

```
downloadTasks.forEach
            {
                if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == url)
                {
                    $0.cancel()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5+ & Alamofire 5.4.1**

```
        AF.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
            tasks.forEach {$0.cancel() }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I got cnoon's answer to work on my own instance of an `Alamofire.Manager`. I have a singleton class called NetworkHelper which has a property called alamoFireManager, which handles all my network requests. I just call the `NSURSession` `invalidateAndCancel()` on that `alamoFireManager` property, reset my manager in `setAFconfig()`, then I'm good to go.

```
class NetworkHelper {

private var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.Manager!

class var sharedInstance: NetworkHelper {
    struct Static {
        static var instance: NetworkHelper?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = NetworkHelper()
    }

    return Static.instance!
}
init(){
    setAFconfig()
}

func setAFconfig(){
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4
    alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
}
func cancelAllRequests() {
    print("cancelling NetworkHelper requests")
    alamoFireManager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
    setAFconfig()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.2

```
let session = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session
session.getAllTasksWithCompletionHandler() { tasks in
    tasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### How to stop the Api calling Alomofire in swift

```
class func StopAPICALL()  {
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
            dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Alamofire5, you can use:

```swift
    /// cancel all request in APIManager session
    /// - Parameter completion: Closure to be called when all `Request`s have been cancelled.
    func cancelAllRequest(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.session.cancelAllRequests(completion: completion)
    }
```