# Cancel a request Alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, http-post, alamofire

I am sending a request which is triggered based on timer. But if I press the back button the request still seems to be active and the response in turns crashes the app. Kindly suggest a way to cancel the request.

Using Xcode 8.2.1
Swift 3

Here is the sample request :

```
Alamofire.request(path!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: createHeader()).responseJSON {
    response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        success(data as AnyObject?)
    case .failure(let error) :
        failure(error as NSError)
    }
}
```

Even tried invalidating the timer on viewDidDisappear but to no help.

Thanks !!

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999892/ios-alamofire-stop-all-requests

Comment: @ImadAli . That is not helpful as invalidating would need to reinitialize the manage and i will not be able to make further calls as of.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Alamofire 4 / Swift 3 / Xcode 8

You can cancel a **single request** as below:

1 - First get the request:

```
let request = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(path!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: createHeader()).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        success(data as AnyObject?)
    case .failure(let error) :
        failure(error as NSError)
    }
}
```

2 - Then, in your **viewDidDisappear**, just call:

`request.cancel()`

---

You can cancel **all requests** as below:

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (sessionDataTask, uploadData, downloadData) in
    sessionDataTask.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    uploadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    downloadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

did you try [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1703) solution:

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default 
sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in 
dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } 
uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } 
downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } 
}
```

i also add a check to verify if is this the request that i want to cancel:

```
dataTasks.forEach
            {
                if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == url)
                {
                    $0.cancel()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT 5**

```
Alamofire.Session.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler({ dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
            dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone, in my case I had a RequestRetrier on the SessionManager that retried the request after it was canceled, so be sure to check there!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
manager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire 5 has a function on `Session` that cancels all requests:

```
Alamofire.Session.default.cancelAllRequests()
```

And another, `withAllRequests`, that can be used to perform an action on the set of active requests.

Docs:  https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#operating-on-all-requests

Also, note that the Alamofire docs state that the underlying `URLSession` object:

> should **NOT** be used to interact with the underlying `URLSessionTask`s. Doing so will break internal Alamofire logic that tracks those tasks.